# Averaging time after converting to Seconds

Tags: average

I have a list of times it takes to review reports
I am averaging time by this method:

Multiply the individual times by 86400 to convert to seconds (example, 00:11:36*86400=696)
Then, divide the total number of seconds by the number of reports

This is where it gets mucky for me.
Lets say the total number of reports are 523.
The total number of seconds is 28855.13333.I divide the number of seconds by reports and get 55.17233907. Then, I divide that by 60 seconds and get 0.919538984.
Is this telling me its 92 seconds?
In another situation,
63 reports
6628 total seconds
6628/63 = 105.2063492
105.2063492/60 = 1.753439153

Now, I believe the decimal part of this result is a fraction of the seconds, so I multiply
0.753439153 * 60 = 45.20634918
So is my result 1 minutes and 45 seconds?
Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since the result of seconds/reports is in seconds (per report) already, there is no need to divide by 60. From your description, you want seconds so...don't do that.

However if you did divide by 60, your result would be interpreted as **minutes**: `.91` minutes is `54.6`seconds.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was something like that. I needed to look at the entire picture. Thank you for that clarification.